# Android, how to load image from server?

Tags: android, image, load

In my app I'm opening a connection to load data. In handset device (Galaxy 2) and tablet p1000 (old 7" tablet with os 2.2) I have no problem and I can get and parse data.

But in another tablet (Samsung 7" plus - Honeycomb) the application crashes. Logcat says:

```
04-05 16:31:33.905: E/AndroidRuntime(4137): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-05 16:31:33.905: E/AndroidRuntime(4137): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
04-05 16:31:33.905: E/AndroidRuntime(4137):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1077)
04-05 16:31:33.905: E/AndroidRuntime(4137):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:477)
04-05 16:31:33.905: E/AndroidRuntime(4137):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:277)
04-05 16:31:33.905: E/AndroidRuntime(4137):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:249)
04-05 16:31:33.905: E/AndroidRuntime(4137):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:136)
04-05 16:31:33.905: E/AndroidRuntime(4137):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
04-05 16:31:33.905: E/AndroidRuntime(4137):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
04-05 16:31:33.905: E/AndroidRuntime(4137):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
04-05 16:31:33.905: E/AndroidRuntime(4137):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
04-05 16:31:33.905: E/AndroidRuntime(4137):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
04-05 16:31:33.905: E/AndroidRuntime(4137):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
04-05 16:31:33.905: E/AndroidRuntime(4137):     at cam.astro.mania.adapters.NewsAdapter.fetchImages(NewsAdapter.java:105)
04-05 16:31:33.905: E/AndroidRuntime(4137):     at cam.astro.mania.adapters.NewsAdapter.setData(NewsAdapter.java:45)
04-05 16:31:33.905: E/AndroidRuntime(4137):     at com.astro.mania.activities.NewsList.displayData(NewsList.java:359)
04-05 16:31:33.905: E/AndroidRuntime(4137):     at com.astro.mania.activities.NewsList.access$4(NewsList.java:358)
04-05 16:31:33.905: E/AndroidRuntime(4137):     at com.astro.mania.activities.NewsList$MyAsyncTask.onPostExecute(NewsList.java:199)
04-05 16:31:33.905: E/AndroidRuntime(4137):     at com.astro.mania.activities.NewsList$MyAsyncTask.onPostExecute(NewsList.java:1)
04-05 16:31:33.905: E/AndroidRuntime(4137):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:590)
04-05 16:31:33.905: E/AndroidRuntime(4137):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:149)
04-05 16:31:33.905: E/AndroidRuntime(4137):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:603)
04-05 16:31:33.905: E/AndroidRuntime(4137):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-05 16:31:33.905: E/AndroidRuntime(4137):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
04-05 16:31:33.905: E/AndroidRuntime(4137):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
04-05 16:31:33.905: E/AndroidRuntime(4137):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-05 16:31:33.905: E/AndroidRuntime(4137):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
04-05 16:31:33.905: E/AndroidRuntime(4137):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
04-05 16:31:33.905: E/AndroidRuntime(4137):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
04-05 16:31:33.905: E/AndroidRuntime(4137):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

my code is:

```
/*-------------------------------
     * Downloading images from server
     * ------------------------------*/
    private Bitmap[] fetchImages(ArrayList<String> urlstr){
        InputStream is= null;
        Bitmap bm = null;
        Bitmap[] bmList = new Bitmap[urlstr.size()];
        
        try {
            for(int i=0; i<urlstr.size(); i++){
                HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet(urlstr.get(i));
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpRequest);
    
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
                is = bufHttpEntity.getContent();
                bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is); 
                bmList[i] = bm;
            }
        }catch ( MalformedURLException e ){
            Log.d( "RemoteImageHandler", "fetchImage passed invalid URL: " + urlstr );
        }catch ( IOException e ){
            Log.d( "RemoteImageHandler", "fetchImage IO exception: " + e );
        }finally{
            if(is!=null)try{
                is.close();
            }catch(IOException e){}
        }
        
        return bmList;
    }
```

Logcat points to `HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpRequest)`. I don't understand what is the meaning of error. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start a new thread for you download and do it there. Inform your main thread via message to  [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) or just wait for thread to finish using join()

Answer (score 1):

[This error](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) says that you are not allowed to perform networking action in the main thread.

You need to do it in another thread and to get the result back asynchronously.

Hope it helps.

Jokahero

Answer (score 0):

You can you this code to load the image to an imageview.

```
 ImageView ImageView =(ImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
   InputStream is = null;
   try {
        is = (InputStream) new URL(ClueImgURL).getContent();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
  Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
  ImageView .setBackgroundDrawable(d);
```

Here  ClueImgURL is the url of the image.